# Vertx server sends a HTML file twice

Tags: html, openshift, vert.x

I'm beginner Java Programmer.
Nowdays I'm trying to make my own chat server by using Vertx, SockJS and Openshift.
The problem is, when I open my openshift webpage, not always but sometimes,
 Vertx server sends a html file twice that makes webpage crash. just like below.

```
<!DOCTYPE html><html>
<head>
....something
</script>
</body>
</html>HTTP/1.1 200 OK
content-type: text/html
Content-Length: 6334

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
 .... something
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

[image: Look like this]

As you can see, Server already sent a message HTTP/1.1 200 OK, but Vertx sever sends a html file once more.
This make my browser show me a plain text, not a html.
My Vertx server script is just like below,

```
public class WebChatVerticle extends AbstractVerticle {

public static JsonArray userList = new JsonArray();
@Override
public void start(Future<Void> fut) throws Exception{
    HttpServerOptions serverOptions = new HttpServerOptions().setMaxWebsocketFrameSize(1000000);
    HttpServer server = vertx.createHttpServer(serverOptions);
    Router router = Router.router(vertx);
    router.route("/").handler(routingContext -> {
          HttpServerResponse response = routingContext.response();
          response
            .putHeader("content-type", "text/html")
            .sendFile("../app-root/repo/webroot/view/index.html");
    });
    router.route().handler(CookieHandler.create());
    SessionStore store = LocalSessionStore.create(vertx);
    SessionHandler sessionHandler = SessionHandler.create(store);
    router.route().handler(sessionHandler);
    server.requestHandler(router::accept)
    .listen(Integer.getInteger("http.port", 8080), System.getProperty("http.address"),result -> {
        if (result.succeeded()) {
            fut.complete();
          } else {
            fut.fail(result.cause());
          }
    });
}
}
```

Usally webpage looks fine and this doesn't happen all the time, maybe just 1/10 chance to happen. 
 But this make me really annoyed. Please help me.

Comment: have you tried adding .end() to the response?

Comment: @JochenBedersdorfer Oh, yes I tried that but it dosen't worked. However, I fixed this problem. I'll write a answer now.

Answer (score 0):

Having tried a lots of method to fix this problem, finally I changed my code like a below.

```
router.route("/").handler(routingContext -> {
      HttpServerResponse response = routingContext.response();
      response
        .putHeader("content-type", "text/html")
        .sendFile("../app-root/repo/webroot/view/index.html");
});
```

to

```
router.route("/").handler(StaticHandler.create()
.setWebRoot("../app-root/repo/webroot").setCachingEnabled(true));
```

Accoding to 
http://vertx.io/docs/vertx-web/java/,

> Configuring the index page
>
> Any requests to the root path / will cause the index page to be
>   served. By default the index page is index.html. This can be
>   configured with setIndexPage.

This works fine so far.
But I can't explain the difference between them, sorry.